# Getting garbled text when using ADTPro with Apple IIc and serial connection

Tags: apple-ii, apple, serial, apple-iic

I am currently having issues while trying to use ADTPro to connect to my Apple IIc and was wondering whether anyone could help me. I am using [this](https://www.ebluejay.com/ads/item/8066323) serial connection kit and trying to bootstrap from ADTPro, but no matter what I seem to try it always ends up sending garbled text to the Apple IIc. I've tried it with my Mac and my Windows PCs and both produce the same result. For what it's worth, "PRINT PEEK(64447)" returns 0 so it seems that my Apple IIc shouldn't have the chip with the timing issue, but I can't quite put my finger on what is going wrong and I haven't found anyone else with the same issue. Here is a picture of what the garbled text looks like:

[image]

Update: Further testing with the baud rate set to 300 (on both PC and Apple IIc) and using Tera Term shows the following interactions with input from Tera Term:

- `@` types successfully

  - `01000000`
- `A` sometimes becomes `P`

  - `01000001` vs `01010000`
- `a` sometimes becomes `X`

  - `01100001` vs `01011000`
- `B` sometimes becomes `h`

  - `01000010` vs `01101000`
- `C` also sometimes becomes `h`

  - `01000011` vs `01101000`
- `D` sometimes becomes `t`

  - `01000100` vs `01110100`

Perhaps there is a pattern there.

Comment: This looks more like a baud rate problem to me. An affected serial chip should at least partially receive correct data. But your screen contents looks completely garbled. Or was there some readable text that has scrolled off the screen?

Comment: @tofro All gibberish from what I can tell, from the start to the bottom. Adjusting the bootstrap speed settings to 2400 just made it print all x's, and adjusting the "pacing" doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Do you have actual terminal software for the //c?  Like Ascii Express or something similar?  I would fire up a terminal on both sides and see if just typing characters back and forth works.  If that test fails, I would try using a different computer to talk to the Apple (maybe ditch the USB to RS232 in favor of a real serial port on another computer).  The thing I would try to nail down is, does the //c communicate in a terminal just fine?  Does it only corrupt data when the USB is used? etc.

Comment: We need a bit more information: The screen shows an attempt to start the Speediboot bootstrap? You did do the <CTRL>A14B dance? Actually, you should see the Apple enter the monitor - but from your screen its clear it stays in BASIC.

Comment: @Geo... I do not unfortunately, and I do not own a computer with a serial port either. Perhaps I can find some way to "bootstrap" a terminal client by hand? For further context, I do own the system utilities disks and they boot successfully if that provides any useful tools.

Comment: @tofro I did do the <CTRL-A> + 14B dance, and I will describe the steps here. Computer turns on and says "Check Disc Drive". Then I <CTRL-reset>. Then I enter IN#2 and click enter. Then I type in <CTRL-A> + 14B and click enter. CTRL-A displays a question mark, typing in 14B shows a dithered square with no text, and pressing enter outputs nothing but a newline. Skipping any of these steps prevents communication, so at least something's happening.

Comment: Here https://www.applefritter.com/content/trouble-adtpro-sending-garbled-text-apple-iie someone aparently had a similar (or same) problem and solved it by simply changing to another *modern* computer.

Comment: @ldrees, I am going to assume you have been all over the ADTPro website, but just in case you haven't I'm putting a link to their Bootstrapping from Bare Metal page https://adtpro.com/bootstrap.html#Starting_from_bare_metal. I did this with ADTPro 1.3 about 10 years ago, and it went pretty smooth, but one thing that I do remember is I had to initially use 300 baud.  I wish I had more to offer.

Comment: Try following the diagnostic suggestions in the various comments at that applefritter URL if you haven't already.

Comment: I've tried the debugging steps mentioned in the forums and updated my original question with the results. I also tried using my M1 mac along with my Intel Mac and Windows PC to no avail. The fact that the terminal is also giving errors sometimes at 300 baud makes this issue a bit different from anything else I can find, as the baud rate is supposedly low enough that the recalled timing issue shouldn't be a problem. I also tried with a data rate of 7 bits instead of 8 with the only difference being along the lines of "A" becoming lowercase "p" rather than capital "P" when it got jumbled.

Comment: @Idrees You have an USB to serial adapter cable? Which chipset it has? FTDI, Silabs, Prolific, CH340? Which exact model?

Comment: @Justme [This](https://www.ebluejay.com/ads/item/8066323) cable set, with the USB adapter saying "FTDI-FT232RL" on it. On my windows machine, it shows that FTDI drivers are installed.

Comment: Just to get it out of the way - the two sides are identically set up with 5/6/7/8 bits, parity odd/even/none, baud rate and lenght of stop bits?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen AFAIK, the apple iic should have the defaults listed [here](http://c64retr.blogspot.com/2013/11/serial-port-communication-on-apple-iic.html?m=1), and I used 8 bits, 1 stop bits, and no parity to match on my PC that was sending the input.

Comment: The issue turned out to be a result of the null modem cable, a replacement cable worked perfectly. I had already opened up the original cable and confirmed that the wiring was correct, so I can only assume it is some sort of loose connection or something. Thanks to everyone who helped with this frustrating issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the issue lied in the IIc null modem cable. After receiving a replacement, the connection worked perfectly and I was able to immediately load ADTPro via the bootstrapping process.

Comment: I'm glad it was the null modem and not the serial port on the //c!